# Do there exist super-Wieferich primes?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

A [Wieferich prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime) is a prime $p$ such that $2^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod{p^2}$.
Denote the order of $2$ modulo $p$ by $O(p)$. Then we can show that a prime $p$ is a Wieferich prime if and only $O(p^2)=O(p)$. Otherwise we have $O(p^2)=pO(p)$.

- What do we know of $O(p^3)$ for Wieferich primes?
- Do there exists super-Wieferich primes, that is, primes $p$ such that $O(p^3)=O(p)$.

Comment: There are not awfully many Wieferich primes around. Check them, and you'll see.

Comment: Of course we can check for the known Wieferich primes. What I wondered is if we know something more general (e.g. a wieferich prime is never super-wieferich, or there exists some, or another general statement about their existence).

Comment: I've had much fun on exploring this. You might like to read my study at http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/fermatquotients.pdf (the immediate relevant part is chap.3). Didn't find any "super-wieferich"-primes but some "generalized wieferich" primes (not to base $2$) and explored that field in a little more generalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We only know of two Wieferich primes $ 1093$ and $3511$, and they are not super-Wieferich.

Naively we should expect that a "random" prime $p$ has probability $1/p^2$ of $2^p \equiv 2 \mod p^3$ (since we know $2^p \equiv 2 \mod p$, there are $p^2$ possible values for $2^p \mod p^3$).  Since $\sum_p 1/p^2 < \infty$, we should expect that there are only finitely many super-Wieferich primes.  Since we've tested lots of primes in the search for more Wieferich primes (up to at least $4.97 \times 10^{17}$) and the sum of $1/p^2$ for those we haven't tested is very small, I am reasonably confident that there are no super-Wieferich primes.  Of course this is not anywhere near a proof.

On the other hand, since $\sum_p 1/p = \infty$ we expect there to be infinitely many Wieferich primes.

EDIT: To support the idea that $2^p - 2 \mod p^3$ should be a random multiple of $p$, here is a plot.  Each black dot $(x,y)$ is obtained as follows:
if $p$ is the $x$'th odd prime, for $1 \le x \le 2000$, $y = z/p^3$ where $0 \le z < p^3$ and $2^p - p \equiv z \mod p^3$.  It looks pretty random to me. But, as I said, this is heuristic.

[image]

Comment: Why should $ \frac{2^p-2}{p}\bmod p$ be randomly distributed ?

Comment: It wouldn't. That's what people call _"heuristic considerations"_.

Comment: It's just heuristic: I know of no reason $2+$ any multiple of $p$ should be favoured over any other.

Comment: Sure but I wonder if there is an heuristic argument for it or if it is just a strengthening of $\{2^p/a \}$ is randomly distributed. The plot suggests the distribution of $\{2^p/p^3\}$ might converge to the same distribution as $\{2^n/n^3\}$, but the answer's argument is more about the rate of convergence.

Comment: it has about a 1/3 chance of being a divisor of p-1 if selected randomly.